# Chrome maximised black screen, missing icons and text

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, kubuntu, kde, google-chrome

So I'm running Ubuntu 12.10, and I've been having issues with the Google Chrome icons going blank until I hover over them. The text on each tab also goes blank often. I presume it's some graphic card incompatibility. It hasn't really bothered me till now.

I've installed KDE over Ubuntu (because Unity) and it seems to have slowly gotten worse. If I maximise a chrome window or increase it's size beyond a certain amount, the window is basically failing to update. New tabs are just black screen. If I load a web page I have to scroll around to force it to update, and sometimes it won't even do that.

I should note it isn't JUST chrome is effected, Eclipse is having issues with blank icons too, but I'm not getting the horrible black screen with that, so I can still work.

I've tried disabling desktop effects (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) but it doesn't help.

Im using an Asus N55SL which has an NVidia GeForce GT 635M 2GB graphics card.

So in summary, this seems to be Desktop environment (KDE and Ubuntu) and application (Chrome and Eclipse) independent. Happy to provide output of terminal commands at request.

Edit: a little more information, I just had to shut my computer down because the keyboard and mouse stopped responding. on restart everything seems fine, but as I remember, the situation slowly gets worse over time. I will update this as and when things start breaking...